# How To Get Selected Item From Menu Button javaFX?

Tags: java, button, javafx, menu

i have just started javaFX and i have made a ButtonMenu with few options. i want to get what user selects from menu.

here is my code so far ->

controller class >

```
@FXML
private JFXTextField locF;
private File file;
private Set<String> extensions;
@FXML
private MenuButton format;


public void openFileBrowser(ActionEvent event){


    DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    chooser.setTitle("JavaFX Projects");
    chooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("c:/"));
    File selectedDirectory = chooser.showDialog(Main.stage);
    locF.setText(selectedDirectory+"");
    extensions=getFileTypes(selectedDirectory.listFiles());//just gets all different types format present in the folder and later add it to menu
    Iterator<String> it=extensions.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
     format.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem(it.next()));
    }
}

private Set<String> getFileTypes(File[] list){
    Set<String> ext=new HashSet<>();
    for (File i:
         list) {

        if (i.isFile()){


                ext.add(i.getName().substring(i.getName().lastIndexOf(".")));



        }

    }

    return ext;
}
```

}

FXML ->

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <top>
      <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="295.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="57.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="295.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="93.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="564.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="311.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="575.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="77.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="575.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="69.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="locF" focusColor="#47c64d" unFocusColor="#821dda" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="browse" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFileBrowser" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="123.0" ripplerFill="#2de823" text="Browse" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="locL" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="143.0" text="Enter Location" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </top>
   <right>
      <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="95.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="61.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="139.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="139.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="98.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="17.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="227.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="227.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <MenuButton fx:id="format" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Format" GridPane.columnIndex="1">

            </MenuButton>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

i have tried going to oracle but haven't found any info. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I ran your code. There are no options to select in your "format" dropdown menu.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson how to add select in menu?

Comment: You should search for very simple examples that only tackle the issue you are facing.

Comment: yes i did search but there is no tutorial/example which i found and helped me out.

Comment: Good question, i will do some research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A  MenuButton  control looks like a button and behaves like a menu.
> When it is activated (by clicking or other  means), it shows a list of
> options in the form of a pop-up menu. The list of options in the menu
> is maintained  in an  ObservableList  whose reference is
> returned by the  getItems()  method. **To execute a  command when a menu
> option is selected, you need to add the  ActionEvent  handler to the
> MenuItems**.

So it has not build in mechanism for detecting which MenuItem is selected...

Except if you are using  `RadioMenuItem`or `CheckMenuItem`with groups,that is other story..In that case you can get the selected item from the `ToggleGroup` you are using to group those buttons.

---

**Solution:**

For each `MenuItem` you have added into the `MenuButton` `ObservableList` add an `actionListener`:

```
 while (it.hasNext()){
     MenuItem item = new MenuItem(it.next());
     item.setOnAction(a->{ //lambda expression
        //..code logic here for each extension
     });
     format.getItems().add(item);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution by doing a Google search.

```
Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);


    ChoiceBox<String> cb = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
    cb.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        String selectedItem = cb.getValue();
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Example");
        alert.setContentText("You clicked " + cb.getItems().get((Integer)newValue));
        alert.showAndWait();
    });


    root.getChildren().add(cb);
    stage.show();
}
```

You can play around with this until you get your desired results.